# Memory efficient way to store many numbers (floats, ints) in a .blend file

Tags: python, add-on

For my addon I need to store large amounts of data in a .blend file (mostly floats, but other types are possible as well).

I tried using a normal `CollectionProperty`. Performance wise this works fine (with `foreach_get` and `foreach_set`). However some rough measures show that Blender stores roughly 128 bytes per float this way, which is quite a lot of overhead and therefor not really acceptable.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Could a numpy array give less overhead and control of item size?

Comment: right, but I can't just store a numpy array in a .blend file afaik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections are indeed not ideal for this use case.

You can store raw arrays in [ID properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/when-should-custom-properties-be-used-instead-of-bpy-props/54043#54043), which will native data types that don't take up excessive space in memory or on-disk. eg:

```
bpy.context.object["my_array"] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

You can assign from an `array` type too:

```
import array
data = array.array('f', [1, 2, 3])
bpy.context.object["my_array"] = data
```

Internally float values are stored with double precision (8 bytes per value), as with Python's floats.

Comment: I have two little follow up question, tell me if I should ask them in a separate question:
1. Blender uses only doubles here, right? Because even if I give it a memory view with floats, it seems to take twice as much memory as expected.
2. Is it possible to access this data more quickly? Like with foreach_set/get?

Comment: It seems like there always has to be a normal Python list as intermediate data type. Even when I have the data as raw array and Blender as well. This is not the case when I use a CollectionProperty (although there I have to create many items in a loop before I can use foreach_set).

Answer (score 0):

For the float / doubles issue:

Let's say X is your double and you only need 3 decimals of precision...

```
from math import floor
floor(X * 1000)
```

Then store your value as an int to conserve space.
Divide by 1000 when importing to get a double value again.

If you need more precision, add a few more 0's on there.
7 decimals of precision...

```
floor(X * 10000000)
```

Divide by 10000000 when importing to get a double value again.
You'd conserve space, but it would take time to do the conversion.