# How can I save a dict in a scene propertyGroup?

Tags: python

I want to save a dict of random information to the scene, per .blend file, the dict updates fine but on reload it is back to its defaults.

```
    bl_info = {
    "name": "Test",
    "author": "Test",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "description": "",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

region_3d_settings = (
            "view_location",
            "view_distance",
            "view_rotation",
            "view_perspective"
        )

class Test_Variables(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    startup_settings = {"clip" : {"start" : 0.01, "end" : 100},
                          "viewport" : {},
                          }

@persistent
def pre_save(scene):

    self_vars = bpy.context.scene.test_vars

    for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':

            for setting in region_3d_settings:
                self_vars.startup_settings["viewport"][setting] = getattr(a.spaces[0].region_3d, setting)

            for s in a.spaces:
                if s.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    self_vars.startup_settings["clip"]["start"] = s.clip_start
                    self_vars.startup_settings["clip"]["end"] = s.clip_end
                    break


classes = (
    Test_Variables,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.test_vars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = Test_Variables)

    bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.append(pre_save)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.test_vars

    if pre_save.__name__ in [hand.__name__ for hand in bpy.app.handlers.save_pre]:
        bpy.app.handlers.save_pre.remove(pre_save)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Nested collection properties seem possible. Have a look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159353/31447

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Make them properties**

In as much as you can define anything to a property group, only those that are defined as `bpy.props` properties, or wired up as `@property` with setter,  will be saved to blender file (or elsewhere).

In example above, to use `bpy.props` and have them saved to blender `clip` would be a pointer property, and `start` a float property of another propertygroup.
Can create a property group with type,

```
clip_class = type("Clip", (PropertyGroup,), 
        {"start" : FloatProperty(),
        }
    )
```

See the `bpy.props` documentation, in particular the setter getter example which emulates how a property is saved on the blend as an ID property on the object.

**Better still**

Alternatively, to save a "junk" dictionary with only string, integer, bool and float values use the rna

As used here

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/54040/15543

can define a custom property on a scene and set arbitrary values in the dictionary that stores values to decorate the UI.  If you add a custom property named "prop" using the UI.  All the details filled in via the popup are saved, and used to decorate the display of the prop in the UI. *Recommend viewing the source of `rna_prop_ui.py`*

We can abuse this system.

```
 C.scene['_RNA_UI']['prop']
<bpy id prop: owner="SCScene", name="prop", address=0x7facac90e108>

>>> C.scene['_RNA_UI']['prop'].to_dict()
{'min': 0.0, 'soft_min': 0.0, 'max': 1.0, 'soft_max': 1.0, 'default': 1.0}
```

Can set, save file

```
>>> foobar = {"foo":True, "bar":100}
>>> C.scene['_RNA_UI']['prop']['foobar'] = foobar
```

and reopen, dictionary remains. The boolean is converted to int.

```
>>> C.scene['_RNA_UI']['prop'].to_dict()
{'min': 0.0, 'soft_min': 0.0, 'max': 1.0, 'soft_max': 1.0, 'default': 1.0, 'foobar': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 100}}
```

Another option is to use json to convert / read string dictionaries and store the dictionary as a string.

In your persistent handler, (add code to handle key errors)

```
self_vars = scene['_RNA_UI']['prop']['foobar']
```

notice `scene` is passed to the handler.